# Storing large files for/with SOLR

Tags: file, solr

I read SOLR isn't for storing files (PDFs, Videos, etc). It can, but it's not its primary purpose. My question: is there any preferred easy to add on way to integrate file storage with SOLR?

I'm making a service which will receive payloads from an external service which we need to process for searching and storing, and SOLR only solves half the problem.

Some how it seems like this is an uncommon case because I'm having a hard time finding any discussions of this.

Comment: If you are forced to add another web service, such as a CMS (content management system), then within your solr doc you can include the URI that ties back to that doc within solr.

Comment: I personally would be concerned that if you try to add the PDF docs (or other raw docs) to solr, then you may impact the indexability and retrieval of the solr docs since less docs will be cached with each file-system-read.  Take a look at the solr admin cloud node page and it will show you the average size/doc and if that becomes too large, then performance could adversely suffer.

Comment: Something else to consider would be related to solr cloud costs.  For example, if using AWS cloud services, the storage type you would need for the solr indexes (block storage) may be more expensive than cheaper storage types such as S3 object storage.  Such solutions using s3 object storage would not need to have a web server to process those requests; the URL/URI would resolve on it's own due to the nature of how S3 works.